# sec:authorize hasPermission problems in conjunction with JSF

Tags: java, spring, jsf, spring-security, jsf-2.2

I am getting weired errors when using sec:authorize access="hasPermission together wit JSF.

My Libs: JSF 2.2.11, spring-faces 2.4.2, spring security 4.0.2, spring-security-taglibs 4.0.2

when I use:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasPermission(#{userManagement.editedUser}, 'addObject')">
```

I get the error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: /secured/users/user.xhtml @10,18 <ui:composition template="/templates/mainLayout.xhtml"> Invalid path : /templates/mainLayout.xhtml
```

STACK:

```
Warnung:   StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException: /secured/users/user.xhtml @10,18 <ui:composition template="/templates/mainLayout.xhtml"> Invalid path : /templates/mainLayout.xhtml
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:179)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:161)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:990)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:178)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:205)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If if enter

```
<sec:authorize access="hasPermission('dummyforTesting', 'addObject')">
```

The Page is displayed appart from the secured area and i get the message:

```
WARN org.springframework.security.access.expression.DenyAllPermissionEvaluator - Denying user bwright permission 'addObject' on object dummyforTesting
```

Is there a known issue with hasPermission and JSF? Any idea what I am missing?

thanks for the Help!

**EDIT 1:**

Ok as far as I can see, the ui:composition error is only a side effect of trying to pass an Object to hasPermission. Still now idea on how to solve this issue though.

Comment: Show more of the HTML page - where do you have a reference to `/templates/mainLayout.xhtml`?

Comment: xhtml starts with :  `<ui:composition template="/templates/mainLayout.xhtml" ...`

the `<sec: ...` part is followed by simple html nothing fancy. If i remove thee sec part everything wors as expected

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
<sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="#{userManagement.editedUser}, addObject">
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<sec:authorize access="hasPermission(@userManagement.editedUser, 'addObject')">
```

Spring EL specifies the usage of "@" ([Ref1](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#el-access-web-beans), [Ref2](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-bean-references)) for bean references.

Answer (score 0):

`DenyAllPermissionEvaluator` is the default `PermissionEvaluator`. You can implement your own and set it for the handler in your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler handler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
    handler.setPermissionEvaluator(permissionEvaluator);
    web.expressionHandler(handler);
}
```